# mysql ifnull where

Tags: sql, mysql, ifnull

i need such query

```
select * from t where
field=ifnull(:param, field) 'it not work's
```

so if param=NULL i have

```
select * from t where field is NULL
```

but if param =4
i have

```
select * from t where field=4
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the case when in where clause AFAIK bot not sure about MySQl,

But the better approach is to translate them,

you can read about that [SQL WHERE clauses: Avoid CASE, use Boolean logic](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/jeffs/archive/2003/11/14/513.aspx)

So

```
select * from t where (:param is null and filed is null) or (filed = :param)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this alternative
this might help you

```
 select * from t where (field = NULL AND param= NULL) OR field ='4'
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for [NULLIF](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_nullif) instead of ifnull

I think better approach would be to use CASE in where clause in your case.

Answer (score 0):

When working with NULL you cannot use arithmetic operators. Try [COALESCE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce) to make a logical if with values integer or NULL

```
mysql> SELECT COALESCE(NULL,1);
    -> 1
mysql> SELECT COALESCE(NULL,NULL,NULL);
    -> NULL
```